# How to get route path to match on mandatory and optional characters in same regex?

Tags: regex, express, routes, express-router

I am struggling getting a route path to match on mandatory and optional characters.

My route is this:

```
  expressRouter.get(['/post/:PostID([0-9]+)(-*)?'], async function (req, res) {  
    let Result;
    const PostID = req.params.PostID;
    try {
        Result = await api.getPost(PostID);
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.code === 404) {
            return res.status(404).send("404 | Page Not Found")
        }
        return res.status(500).send(error);
        return res.status(500).send("500 | Internal Server Error");
    }
    res.status(200).json(Result);
});
```

I am trying to match routes like this:

```
/1079-my-favourite-sports
/1080
/1081-new-car
```

The only mandatory part is the `([0-9]+)` which gives me the `PostID`. The rest of it i.e. `(-.*)` which is a hyphen followed by any characters is optional but is part of a URL slug that needs to be there.

How can I write my path regex so that it will match on all the routes above? Tried using [Express Route Tester](http://forbeslindesay.github.io/express-route-tester/) but getting nowhere other than matching on the first part `([0-9]+)`

Comment: The optional part looks fine. Should “:PostID” be in the regex? Try removing it. Without it, it [works](https://rubular.com/r/uHE8j6RDf47mB9)

Comment: What Express version do you use? The regex expansion with older 4.x is quirky, where `.*` is interpreted as `\.(.*)`. Try this: `/:PostID(\d+)(?:-*)?`

Comment: @PeterThoeny your regex worked perfectly! not entirely sure how you came up with it but its great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Express Rout 1.7.0 and later use this to get the PostID key and an optional Slug key:

```
/:PostID(\d+):Slug(-.*)?
```

Older version (Express 4.x) is quirky, where `.*` is interpreted as `\.(.*)`. Try this:

```
/:PostID(\d+):Slug(-*)?
```